# how to work with contact list of iphone

Tags: iphone

Can anybody tell me how to work with contact list of iphone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Address Book Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 2):

Hope to find this helpful.

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);    
for( int i = 0 ; i < nPeople ; i++ )
{
    ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i );

    //Get First Name
    NSString* firstName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    //Get Last Name
    NSString* lastName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
}
```